# Slurm srun --uid behavior

Tags: slurm, uid

We are trying to use slurm in our uni lab but we can't quite understand slurmUser behavior.

For instance:
If I run srun while I'm logged in as the user 'acnazarejr' (`srun -n1 id -a`), then I would expect something like this:

`uid=80000001637(acnazarejr) gid=80000000253(domain user) groups=80000000253(domain user),1001(slurm)`

But this is what I get:

`uid=1001(slurm) gid=1001(slurm) groups=1001(slurm), 27(sudo), docker(999)`

Even if run (`srun --uid=80000001637 -n1 id -a`) I get the same result. We are using LDAP across all nodes and 'slurm' user can't access the user's home folder, which is important to us.

Is this the expected behavior? I'm almost sure that in earlier tests I was getting my user as output instead of slurm, but I can't replicate it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Your  `slurm.conf`  probably contains

```
SlurmdUser=slurm
```

while it should be

```
SlurmdUser=root
```

The `SlurmdUser` is the user running the `slurmd` daemon, which must be root, or another account able to demote to the submitting user's account.

Not to be mixed up with `SlurmUser`, the user running the `slurmctld` daemon which should be a regular user, often named `slurm`.